# Effect of perturbation on softmax

Tags: taylor-expansion, perturbation-theory, neural-networks

Let's say we have the following function
$$S_i(\textbf{x},T)=\frac{\exp(f_i(\textbf{x})/T)}{\sum_{j=1}^N\exp(f_j(\textbf{x})/T)}$$
where $f_{i=1,\dots,N}(\textbf{x})$ represents the output of a neural network. We want to add a perturbation
$$\tilde{\textbf{x}}=\textbf{x}-\epsilon\ \text{sgn}\left(-\nabla_\textbf{x}\log S_i(\textbf{x},T) \right) $$
The result should be:
$$\log S_i(\tilde{\textbf{x}},T)=\log S_i(\textbf{x},T)+\epsilon||\nabla_\textbf{x}\log S_i(\textbf{x},T)||_1+o(\epsilon)$$
The paper says that this is the first order Taylor expansion, but I cannot figure how it has been derived. Any hint? Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing to do here other than substitute the perturbation into the first order expansion of $x \mapsto \log S_i(x,T)$. The derivative is still in symbolic form in the last equation!

Comment: Yes, but the perturbation affects $f(\textbf{x})$, which I don't know how to take into account. What would you do here?

Comment: And also, are you suggesting to first expand $log(S_i)$ and then applying the perturbation?

Comment: I am just suggesting that if you have a vector $g$ and another $h_k =\operatorname{sgn} g_k$, then $h^Tg = \|g\|_1$. There is really nothing to the formula other than that.